# Multiple forms and persistence in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webforms

I'm gathering input data via a Django like validated form and then upon validating loading  new form from and then validating and then I wish to send to the data store. I'd like to perform temporary storage on the first form, in case the user does not enter the full details on form two I don't see much point of adding to the datastore. So how should I persist the data between forms? Each form has its own handler and post section.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The natural place to persist data between forms is in the user's [session](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http_session#Web_server_session_management); every fields in your multi-form wizard would be stored in session until the last form where, after the confirmation, the data should be finally persisted in the DataStore.

Since Google App Engine does not provide session in the python environment, I would suggest you to install a neat library for this purpose: [gae-sessions](https://github.com/dound/gae-sessions).

Gae-sessions is not magic but it uses [cookies](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass.html#Request_cookies)+[memcache](https://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/python/memcache/)+[datastore](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/) for session management; so, if you don't like to install a third-party library, you have the ingredients to cook your own session library.

Answer (score -1):

I could describe the options, but this blogpost by Nick Johnson describes it perfectly:

[Storage options on App Engine](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/11/Storage-options-on-App-Engine)